# Zoom in when the arrow from drop-down listed is selected

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have been able to find some code that zoom in when a cell containing a drop-down list is selected and then zoom out when a cell without a drop-down list is selected. I was wondering if there is a simple way to zoom in when the arrow to show the list is selected, and then zoom out when a value in the drop-down list has been selected. After some researches, I have not been able to find what is the corresponding target value for the arrow. The code I am currently using is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
    Dim bZoom As Boolean
    Const IncreasedZoomPercentage = "150"                 '<<=== Change to suit
    Const NormalZoomPercentage As Long = "70"      '<<=== Change to suit

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        GoTo XIT
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Rng = Me.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                bZoom = True

            End If
        End If
    End If

XIT:
    With ActiveWindow
        If bZoom Then
            .Zoom = IncreasedZoomPercentage
             Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Else
            .Zoom = NormalZoomPercentage
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are no events triggered from a data validation drop-down.  You can (via a convoluted path) run some code  when you click the drop-down, but that code can't set the Zoom.

Comment: Or maybe consider this: https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal14.html

Comment: Thanks you, would have like to keep working with the build-in drop-down list from the data validation. But will take a look.